# Converting text cases of a variable subset to uppercase to enable me read as a single item

Tags: r

I'm currently working on analyzing a dataset but I'm having issues with a subset (Voice) of a particular variable (contact_type) as it has two different text cases. How do I merge this on R to change or read "VOICE" and "Voice" as the same subset? Please see below a reproducible example

I tried converting the subset (Voice) of the variable (Contact_type) to VOICE using to.upper but it's not working for that

```
g<- read.csv("Sample_data.csv", header = T)
summary(g$contact_type)
       CHAT   EMAIL Unknown   Voice   VOICE 
 14   14425    1281     118   14405   69757
```

I expected the output to be;

```
summary(g$contact_type)
       CHAT   EMAIL Unknown   VOICE 
 14   14425    1281     118   84162
```

Comment: Try changing upper case `g$contact_type <- toupper(g$contact_type)`  and then get the `table(g$contact_type)`

Comment: Thanks @akrun The code worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can convert the column to upper case and then do the `table`

```
g$contact_type <- toupper(g$contact_type)
table(g$contact_type)
```